# Spark job takes a long time to read data from HDFS file using wholeTextFiles

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I want to process data from the HDFS file using the Spark Java code. While processing files, I am performing simple transformation such as replace a new line with space and find patterns using regex from the file. I used the wholeTextFiles method to read data from HDFS files but it took 2 hours to process only 4 MB files.

Spark code:

```
public class TransformationOper {
public static void main(String[] args){    
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark RDD Filter").setMaster("local[2]")
 .set("spark.yarn.queue","llap").set("spark.executor.instances", "4").set("spark.executor.memory","4g")
           .set("spark.executor.cores", "2").set("spark.driver.memory","2g")
           .set("sun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo","true").set("sun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo","true");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
JavaPairRDD<String, String> textFile = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020"+args[0]);
  JavaRDD<String> re = textFile.map( t -> t._2);    
  JavaRDD<String> r2 = re.map( s -> s.replaceAll("\r\n|\n", " ")); 
r2.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020"+args[1]); 
sc.close();
}
}
```

I tried to increase spark executor memory to 15g with 4 executor instances still it took 2 hours.
I have 1 master with 56GiB memory,8 cores, and 3 workers with 28 GiB memory,8 cores.
How to improve the performance of the spark job using these nodes configurations.

Thanks,

Comment: is this related the machine memory? if not then increase the executors and decrease the memory per executor.

Comment: share your code

Comment: ...or better yet, look at Spark UI to see what stage takes the longest and focus on it

Comment: @Lamanus, I have added spark executor configuration in my post.

Comment: @GaurangShah, I have added Spark code in my post.